# Description of the PDE $u_{\xi\xi}=a^2u_{yy}-u_{\xi}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, terminology

I have the following PDE:

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\xi^2}=a^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial\xi}$$

First of all, this is a PDE, right? And after that is nonlinear and is it homogeneous?

Comment: It is linear, it is written improperly as the symbol of partial derivative is missing and, yes, it is a pde.

Comment: @Jon And is it homogeneous?

Comment: Yes, it is homogeneous